# Weird behavior in IE/Firefox regarding $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Tags: php, internet-explorer, redirect

In an php-based application I've been coding, I have the following small block of code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
```

In my application, I use framesets and frames.  This code is present in the main content area frame, and upon execution in IE, creates an infinite loop which kills the browser unless I manually stop loading.

The purpose of this code is to detect if there is a query string appended to the url, and if so, redirect to that query string.  I've primarily been developing using chrome and <strike>and firefox</strike>, and today decided to test it in IE9.  I have not tested it in any previous versions, but so far this behavior only occurs in IE, and I'm frankly stumped on why such is happening.  I've searched for similar questions here and on the internet, but so far no dice.

**Edit**

As I noted with an earlier edit, I am using framesets and frames to control the interface.  The left-hand frame, a side bar, contains links with a base target of the main 'content' area frame.  The content of the content area frame contains javascript that appends a query string to the parent window's url, so that when the index page is visited(with the query string present), it will redirect the content frame to that specific page.

This works perfectly fine in Chrome.  Not IE(or firefox, which I just discovered as of this edit).  Ie instead redirects to the index page, the page containing the frameset, and it does this forever, creating sidebar after sidebar.

Comment: Have you ever tried getting what's inside `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` (for example by echoing it out)?

Comment: @AlvinWong I have, nothing is echoed, though the below answer, paired with your comment got me thinking along lines that allowed me to solve my issue.

Comment: ... you could at least mention what solved it.

Comment: @ceejayoz Doing so, a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of hate myself for not thinking of this sooner, given how horribly simple it is.  All I did, was check if `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` was empty, as so:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != '') {
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
```

And that solved the problem of the index page creating infinite nested framesets and frames.

Comment: np. just trying to keep SO clean... :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['Redirect'] ) && isset( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['Redirect'] = true;
    header( "Location: " . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] );
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not solve the problem; the infinite loop still executes.  I will attempt to be more specific in my question above to better explain the problem.

Comment: Try the above. Set a session variable. If it's not set, it will set the session var, and redirect you. Once it redirects, it will already be set, and not redirect you.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, however your answer, paired with Alvin's comment, got me thinking along a line that allowed me to solve this.  I will be posting what I used to solve this issue in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be your problem at all, but as per HTTP/1.1, redirection requires **the full absolute path including the hostname**. So perhaps try this:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

Or another suggestion is to avoid using the full querystring (like `?thispage.php`), but to use a GET parameter instead (like `?path=thispage.php`).

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = $_GET['page'];
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```